# KDB: last records of xgroup

Tags: kdb

I have a table and I used xgroup to group by a certain column.

```
`col1 xgroup Tab
```

Then I get a list inside every field.

```
col1       aa                                   bb     
---------------------------------------------------
654301841  ("DFIDXARB";"DFIDXARB)               ("2018";"2018")
529406294  ("DFIDXARB";"DFIDXARB";"DFIDXARC")   ("2018";"2017";"2013")
657471294  ("DFIDVVVB";"DFIDAAAA")              ("2018";"2019")
655649664  ("DFIDVVVR";"DFIDAAAX")              ("")
```

How do I get the last values instead? Like below:

```
col1       aa                                   bb     
---------------------------------------------------
654301841  "DFIDXARB                           "2018"
529406294  "DFIDXARC"                          "2013"
657471294  "DFIDAAAA"                          "2019"
655649664  "DFIDAAAX"                          ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use select...by Q-SQL query.

```
    q) select by col1 from tbl
```

Example:

```
    q) t:([]id:1 2 1 2 3;v:1 2 3 4 5;n:`a`b`c`d`e)
    q) select by id rom t

  id| v n
  --| ---
  1 | 3 c
  2 | 4 d
  3 | 5 e
```

Answer (score 2):

Another good option is to use `fby`

```
q)t:([]id:1 2 1 2 3;v:1 2 3 4 5;n:`a`b`c`d`e)
```

You can specify first or last

```
q)select from t where i=(first;i)fby id
id v n
------
1  1 a
2  2 b
3  5 e

q)select from t where i=(last;i)fby id
id v n
------
1  3 c
2  4 d
3  5 e
```

Or you can specify a vertical slice by index

```
q)select from t where i=(@[;1];i)fby id
id v n
------
1  3 c
2  4 d
```

Comment: fby solution is costly for this particular problem compared to simple grouping approach and thats because qsql considered this grouping(last item by col) as a special case and handles that internally. But fby is useful(and mostly the correct way) for other scenarios for ex selecting rows for particular index by column like you mentioned.